# How to make a 2 column flexbox by iterating over array in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

im trying to get a 2 columns flexbox layout in react-native by iterate over an array of objects. i have 1 solution which is more a hack as a solution. And the order in this hack is not the correct.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <View>
        {cars.slice(0, 3).map((item, i) => {
            return (
                <View key={i}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => buttonClickedHandler(item.id)}
                        style={{ 
                            backgroundColor : state.checkin == item.id ? theme.colors.primary : theme.colors.primary+'40',
                            marginTop: 20,
                            width: 150,
                            height: 150,
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            padding: 10,
                            borderRadius: 100,
                            borderColor: theme.colors.primary,
                            borderWidth:3 
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={{fontSize: 15, color: state.checkin == item.id ? 'white' : theme.colors.primary}}>{item.funk}</Text>
                        <Text style={{fontSize: 25, color: state.checkin == item.id ? 'white' : theme.colors.primary}}>{item.name}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            );
        })}
    </View>
    <View>
        {cars.slice(3, 6).map((item, i) => {
            return (
                <View key={i}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => buttonClickedHandler(item.id)}
                        style={{ 
                            backgroundColor : state.checkin == item.id ? theme.colors.primary : theme.colors.primary+'40',
                            marginTop: 20,
                            width: 150,
                            height: 150,
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            padding: 10,
                            borderRadius: 100,
                            borderColor: theme.colors.primary,
                            borderWidth:3 
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={{fontSize: 15, color: state.checkin == item.id ? 'white' : theme.colors.primary}}>{item.funk}</Text>
                        <Text style={{fontSize: 25, color: state.checkin == item.id ? 'white' : theme.colors.primary}}>{item.name}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
             );
        })}
    </View>
</View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        padding: 20
    }
})
```

Do u have any idea to make it more flexible in the correct ordering left to right and not up  to down?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, dynamically based on number of columns in one `map`.

```
const noCols = 2; // configure the columns, so that can change easily.
const noItems = Math.ceil(cars.length / 2);

<View style={styles.container}>
  {Array.from({ length: noCols }, (_, ci) => {
    return (
      <View key={`col_${ci}`}>
        {cars.slice(ci * noItems + 0, ci * noItems + noItems).map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <View key={i}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => buttonClickedHandler(item.id)}
                style={{
                  backgroundColor:
                    state.checkin == item.id
                      ? theme.colors.primary
                      : theme.colors.primary + "40",
                  marginTop: 20,
                  width: 150,
                  height: 150,
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  padding: 10,
                  borderRadius: 100,
                  borderColor: theme.colors.primary,
                  borderWidth: 3,
                }}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 15,
                    color:
                      state.checkin == item.id ? "white" : theme.colors.primary,
                  }}
                >
                  {item.funk}
                </Text>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color:
                      state.checkin == item.id ? "white" : theme.colors.primary,
                  }}
                >
                  {item.name}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  })}
</View>;
```